# Powershell: Get object value to int array

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, casting

I'm fairly new to PowerShell

Can someone please explain the most simple way to copy values from an object into a basic integer array without also copying the original object.

Sorry if this is confusing, but what I mean is that I want to capture object values and put them in an integer array where I can then do simple arithmetic on the values

For example

```
$ComputerCpu = Get-WmiObject win32_processor -computer "MyComputer" | `
    Select-Object {$_.LoadPercentage}
```

On a Windows Server 2008 VM at work this returns two values

I want to get an average so I tried

```
$average = ($ComputerCpu[0] + $ComputerCpu[1]) / 2
```

This cannot work as the values are not of type Int.

I tried casting the values

```
$average = ([int]$ComputerCpu[0] + [int]$ComputerCpu[1]) / 2
```

But this results in a cannot convert error.

I know what the problem is but it would be great if someone could explain the fundamental solution to this as I run into this problem a lot and I know there must be a defined solution or a way to avoid this entirely.

Thanks.

**PS:** If possible please **don't** provide an alternative solution, as I really want to know how to get an objects values into an integer array so as to perform arithmetic on those values.

Thanks.

Comment: `Select-Object` -> `ForEach-Object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to EBGreen's answer, you could use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter of `Select-Object`:

```
$ComputerCpu = Get-WmiObject win32_processor -computer "MyComputer" |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty LoadPercentage
```

The rest of your code would work then.

Comment: Thank you. This works where @EBGreen solution did not (but I don't know why).

Answer (score 1):

Reference the property not the entire object. So:

```
$average = ($ComputerCpu[0].LoadPercentage + $ComputerCpu[1].LoadPercentage) / 2
```

Comment: For some reason this returns $average as 0

Comment: @ATtheincredibleaf possibly the average was zero at the time (or less than 1 and truncated to `[int]`)?